# Can sump pump drain pipes be installed without breaking concrete?

Tags: sump-pump

I am installing a sump pump well in basement. From the well i would like to drive into the earth horizontally  a drain pipe to remove excess water under the concrete floor. Would a hard white PVC pipe work for this application. Would it get water from the surrounding earth?

Comment: Driving PCV pipe. Drain pipe is thinwall, and even thickwall doesn't have enough strength to _drive_. How do you plan on keeping dirt out of the end? And only steel would be able to handle the dirt displacement if you've capped it so dirt won't drive into the pipe and create a labor intensive and expensive earth core sample project.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not...I've never seen anything like what you want to do in the 25 years I've been waterproofing basements. Perforated PVC pipe needs to be at least buried in gravel and preferably a filter fabric too. Check out the video on [home page](http://www.aridbasementwaterproofing.com)e.